# MFC application crashing outside VS on creation of a dialog box

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

My application works fine when run from inside Visual Studio, but crashes if I use the EXE file to run it. [The debug exe]

The problem arises when the application reaches this line of code:

```
            nmax=2*(nrows+rows);
            create_progrcntl(L"Processing please wait"); // Crashes here
            pgr->m_pgr.SetRange32(1,nmax);
            pgr->m_pgr.SetStep(1);
```

The function create_progresscntl is:

```
 void import::create_progrcntl(CString header)
{

 pgr = new CPgr;
 pgr->Create(IDD_PROGRESS,this);
 pgr->SetWindowTextW(header);
    pgr->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);    
}
```

I use this function a couple of other places as well and it causes no errors what so ever.
Its just for the function `import::processENSAT_MasterSlave()` that it crashes.

It runs fine inside VS, but crashes if I run the EXE outside.

I attached the process to the VS debugger. This is my call stack, just after the crash:

```
   ntdll.dll!7729e3be()     
   [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll]  
   ntdll.dll!7729e023()     
   kernel32.dll!751914dd()  
   msvcr100d.dll!_free_base(void * pBlock)  Line 50 + 0x13 bytes    
   msvcr100d.dll!_free_dbg_nolock(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse)  Line 1431 + 0x9 bytes   C++
   msvcr100d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse)  Line 1265 + 0xd bytes  C++
   mfc100ud.dll!operator delete(void * p)  Line 347 + 0xc bytes C++
   mfc100ud.dll!operator delete[](void * p)  Line 360 + 0x9 bytes   C++
   mfc100ud.dll!COccManager::PostCreateDialog(_AFX_OCC_DIALOG_INFO * pDlgInfo)  Line 239 + 0x12 bytes   C++
   mfc100ud.dll!CWnd::CreateDlgIndirect(const DLGTEMPLATE * lpDialogTemplate, CWnd * pParentWnd, HINSTANCE__ * hInst)  Line 413 C++
   mfc100ud.dll!CDialog::CreateIndirect(const DLGTEMPLATE * lpDialogTemplate, CWnd * pParentWnd, void * lpDialogInit, HINSTANCE__ * hInst)  Line 263    C++
   mfc100ud.dll!CDialog::CreateIndirect(void * hDialogTemplate, CWnd * pParentWnd, HINSTANCE__ * hInst)  Line 240 + 0x16 bytes  C++
   mfc100ud.dll!CDialog::Create(const wchar_t * lpszTemplateName, CWnd * pParentWnd)  Line 222 + 0x14 bytes C++
   mfc100ud.dll!CDialog::Create(unsigned int nIDTemplate, CWnd * pParentWnd)  Line 673 + 0x1a bytes C++
   Sar_CCD.exe!import::create_progrcntl(ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > header)  Line 370 + 0x27 bytes  
   Sar_CCD.exe!import::processENSAT_MasterSlave()  Line 1760    
   Sar_CCD.exe!import::Select_process_func()  Line 2758 
   Sar_CCD.exe!import::OnBnClickedBtnProcess()  Line 340
```

Full code:
http://sharetext.org/ZKKp

---

SOLVED: buf was initialized as `buf=new char[6];`. Later 21 bytes were read into it. Thank you so much @atzz

Comment: Have you tried compiling against Multi-threaded Debug DLL? "_free_dbg_nolock" makes me think there might be a thread race.

Comment: @user1240436 - Its set to /MDd

Comment: Advice 1: set up MS symbol server path: `set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=d:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` (read here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503). This will allow to see names of the ntdll functions in the stack trace and maybe provide useful clues.

Comment: Advice 2: next thing I'd do is ensure that there is no buffer overflow with `master_dataout`, `slave_dataout`, `buffer` and all other things which are `delete[]`'d. I tried to look at your code but there are too many places when `delete[]` is called. (In good C++ code, there are no explicit deletes at all). Most probably it's a heap corruption of some sort, possibly due to a buffer overflow.

Comment: I did this:
  ntdll.dll!77b2e3be()  
  ntdll.dll!77b2e023()  
  kernel32.dll!752514dd()

Comment: @atzz shoud I look at all the things that are deleted in the processENSAT_MasterSlave() functions?

Comment: You mean, you've set up the symbol server and it didn't work? Did you set it in the global system properties? Did you restart the debugger? Your firewall doesn't block debugger from accessing the Internet? Anyway, if you can't get it working quickly, don't waste your time -- I think it's better spent on other things like checking for heap corruption.

Comment: Yes, crash happens within delete[] so it's a logical next point of inquiry to check that nothing tries to write behind the last element of each array that's subsequently deleted. Unfortunately with heap corruption it might be some unrelated code.. So I'd reserve some extra space at the end of all these arrays, initialize it with some telltale value, and check that this value is still intact before delete[].

Comment: @atzz it was a heap corruption. Buf was initialized as `buf=new char[6];` but I read 21 bytes into it later. Please propose your comment as a solution so I can select it as the answer. Thanks :)